# How to compile libgfortran to run on iOS arm64 architecture?

Tags: ios, linker, fortran, arm, gfortran

I have a huge chunk of Fortran code that I need to run on iOS device (within an iOS app, that I will talk to like Objective-C -> C -> Fortran).

I was able to compile that Fortran code for `arm64` using `dragonegg`. However in the linking phase I'm missing a lot of symbols from `gfortran` library.

I tried to compile the `gfortran` file by file with Xcode, but it's quite problematic. I would prefer to at least use the `configure` and `make` to somehow bring me closer to the result but seems like `--target=arm-apple-darwin` is not really supported.

Any idea how to create `libgfortran` that is built for `arm64`? perhaps someone has some pre-built `libgfortran` for `arm64`?

Comment: gfortran has an option `-static-libgfortran` whose purpose is to embed `libgfortran` statically in the executable. Have you tried it? It sometimes require an extra install to have a copy of the static library, and not only the dynamic binding.

Comment: static library would still need to be built for arm64 right ?

Comment: Yes, the appropriate `libgfortran.a` (I don't remember if the static library filename extension is `.a` as on linux, though) must be available.

Comment: well indeed libgfortran.a is created but it is for x86_64 architecture and that won't run on an arm64 device :P gfortran sources are fortran and c mixture, so i guess fortran needs to be compiled with dragonegg, c with clang and then combined somehow, but it is far from simple

Comment: It is probably not simple. I wanted to point out the `-static-libgfortran` flags but my knowledge of cross compilation is null, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross compile many configure and Makefile based libraries by running `./configure` for a static library as usual, and changing the compiler and linker when you call `make`. This can be done by the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export SDK=iphoneos
export CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch arm64"
export CC="xcrun --sdk $SDK clang"
export CPP="xcrun --sdk $SDK cpp -D__arm__"
export LD="xcrun --sdk $SDK clang"
make -e
```